# C# on Linux: How to enumerate the computers on the local network?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, network-programming

How can I enumerate all machine names and IPs of remote computers in the local network ?

**Note: NOT on Windows (how to do that one finds via google), I need something that works on Linux !**
Or a C/C++ sample would also do it, I can call libc from C#.

Comment: You need to re-frame your question. It sounds like you're asking for computers on a Windows Workgroup network. This is distinct from computers on a Windows domain, or OSX/Linux computers on other types of non-windows networks.

Comment: Just computers (windows & Linux ones) that are connected with wire and wireless to the same router. Standard installation computers, dhcp, no domain, no nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can run smbtree make sure samba is installed.

run smbtree which will show all the domain, computer and public share on the network.Write this detail in a file and use this file to get required info

**See the output of smbtree**

```
[paul@RHEL4b ~]$ smbtree
Password: 
WORKGROUP
    \\W2000          
PEGASUS
    \\WINXP          
    \\RHEL4B                        Pegasus Domain Member Server
        \\RHEL4B\ADMIN$                 IPC Service (Pegasus Domain Member Server)
        \\RHEL4B\IPC$                   IPC Service (Pegasus Domain Member Server)
        \\RHEL4B\domaindata             Active Directory users only
    \\HM2003
```

`WORKGROUP`, `PEGASUS` are domain name

`W2000`, `WINXP`, `RHEL4B`, `HM2003` these are server name

`RHEL4B\ADMIN$`, `RHEL4B\IPC$`, `RHEL4B\domaindata` these are the shares

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source of **smbtree** from samba.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to send out a broadcast icmp packet, and see who responds, and count that.  This should be doable in a pretty standard manner with any programming language that has standard networking libraries for tcp/ip.

Comment: You mean ping an entire range.

Comment: That's what ping does, it sends an ICMP packet out with an echo request.  If it's sent out to the broadcast address for the network, all the computers on the network will see it and respond.  This is something that is basic to networking concepts.  The broadcast address is the IP address AND'ed with the subnet mask.  Try it with ping, and you'll see what I'm talking about (in Linux, ifconfig will tell you what the broadcast address is for the network, and also make sure your router allows these packets).

Comment: The idea is good, just that none of the computer responds. I read that so far, that's pretty normal.